# Python Twitter Sentiment Analysis Loss/Accuracy Not Changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, twitter, keras, sentiment-analysis

I'm following [this](https://ahmedbesbes.com/sentiment-analysis-on-twitter-using-word2vec-and-keras.html) tutorial for a twitter sentiment analysis project using Python, Tensorflow, Keras, and word2vec.

It's a mostly copy-and-paste tutorial but there are some missing elements that I've figured out. The main changes were in the processing of the data, like adding headers to the tweets csv.
Look at Christopher Pepe's comment in the comments section- he outlines some of the other changes.
I'd say there are only about 10 lines that I changed due to deprecated functions, etc.

My code runs but the network's values aren't right. For all 9 epochs, the loss is around 0.50 and the accuracy is around 0.79. In the tutorial, the final accuracy is 79%, but I think it's a coincidence that they're the same since my values never change.

[See this attached screenshot of the epoch results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8KE6.png)

This is only my 2nd tutorial so I'm not sure how to solve this. Plotting the word vectors in bokeh yields [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olu6B.png), which looks different than the tutorial's. But the word relations make sense so I don't think that's the issue.

I could try changing the learning rate, but beyond that I'm not sure what else to do. Any advice is greatly appreciated. I can post the code as well if that's helpful.

Comment: Did you use the same language/stopwords/stemming? did you filter emoticons, images, http[s]-links? BTW: What's the corpus?

Comment: Yes, everything is the same as the tutorial. The filters were for '@', '#', and 'http' and removed them. The rest that couldn't be tokenized were discarded also. The corpus is created from the same body of tweets